# C++ float questions

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm having a hard time with floats & doubles concept.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const float classA = 15.00f;
    const float classB = 12.00f;
    const float classC = 9.00f;
    int soldA,
    soldB,
    soldC;
    float total = 1.00f;

    std::cout << "How many Class A tickets where sold? : ";
    std::cin >> soldA;
    std::cout << "How many class B tickets were sold? : ";
    std::cin >> soldB;
    std::cout << "How many Class C tickets were sold? : ";
    std::cin >> soldB;

    printf("%f\n", total = (classA * soldA) + (classB * soldB) + (classC * soldC));

    std::cout <<"The total amount collected : $" << total << endl;
}
```

At the last line, I want to print total to be the float in precision of 2 (like dollars), but in the printf works fine when I compile it, but it loses the precision at the last line.

How do I fix this? Or show the precision?

Comment: [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: don't store monetary values in floats. use integers (e.g.: cents)

Comment: The `printf` does not do what you think it does... It only prints, and also is C legacy function so avoid using it in C++ anyway. Just move the assignment to `total` into its own line, do not put it into `printf` arguments (that's valid in C/C++, but generally confusing, and here you seem to think it does something special together with `printf`, but it does not).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: for that matter, don't store monetary values in doubles. any reasonable representation of monetary values should be able to deal with the foreign [debt of US of A, to the penny](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/NP/debt/current).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: that's just silly. for most systems, that's clearly over-engineering.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: These numbers are all itnegers.  There is no roundoff.

Comment: You write to `soldB` twice and `soldC` never.

Comment: @hyde: `printf` is part of the C++ standard, not "a C legacy function".  While it leaves some things to be desired (type safety, extensibility), `iostream` objects are much more painful when dealing with complicated numerical formatting.  Both have good and bad points, and there are appropriate uses for both.

Comment: @tmyklebu: you mean those `float`s are *integers*? lol.

Comment: @StephenCanon `printf` comes from `cstdio` header, for for starters, with that *c* in the name. It also does not support C++ data types directly, and for example to print a string, you need `c_str` method, that *c* in the name again. So I think it is completely fair to say `printf` is a C legacy function. Avoiding using it is matter of opinion and situation, I can agree with that.

Comment: @hyde: `std::vector` comes from the `vector` header, which also has a `c` in its name.  I do not see your point.

Comment: @tmyklebu Ok, I thought it was obvious. The *c* in name of some headers such as `cstdio` does mean it matches (with C++ namespace added) the C standard library header with matching name (`stdio.h` in this case).

Comment: @hyde: Yes, `printf` is also in C.  I do not think this alone is cause to avoid it.  (Especially in favour of the `iostream` library.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const float classA = 15.00f;
    const float classB = 12.00f;
    const float classC = 9.00f;
    int soldA,soldB,soldC;
    float total = 1.00f;

    std::cout << "How many Class A tickets where sold? : ";
    std::cin >> soldA;
    std::cout << "How many class B tickets were sold? : ";
    std::cin >> soldB;
    std::cout << "How many Class C tickets were sold? : ";
    std::cin >> soldC;

    printf("%f\n", total = (classA * soldA) + (classB * soldB) + (classC * soldC));

    std::cout.precision(2);     // set precision
    std::cout << std::fixed;    // use the precision for numbers like 66.000000
    std::cout <<"The total amount collected : $" << total << endl;
}
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the precision on `std::cout` like this:

```
std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout <<"The total amount collected : $" << total << endl;
```

or you can also set it like this:

```
std::cout <<"The total amount collected : $" << std::setprecision(2) << total << endl;
```